# How to make circle image in tcpdf?

Tags: image, geometry, tcpdf

In `tcpdf` `Image()` makes image. But it in `rectangle` shape.

> **1.** How I can make image in `circle` (rounded) shape in `tcpdf`?
>   **2.** May be with `Circle()`? If yes, then how I can do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found very good way. You can use image clipping. The code:

```
$pdf->StartTransform();
// set clipping mask
$pdf->StarPolygon(30, 28, 22, 90, 3, 0, 1, 'CNZ');
$pdf->Image('your-image', 8, 6, 44, 44, '', 'URL', '', true, 300);
$pdf->StopTransform();
```

More details: [HERE](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_034.phps)

Comment: by editing the last '1' to another number you can change the shape, for example to octagon or pentagon :)

Comment: `$pdf->Circle(30, 28, 22, 0, 360, 'CNZ');` rather than `StarPolygon()` as a 'circle image' is asked for

Comment: If anyone could explain those strange parameters... :-(

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try make it with CSS - print image as html:

   ```php
   $html = <<<EOD
       <img src="/images/image.jpg" class/style="some class or style">
   EOD;
   $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
   ```
2. Also You can try draw white geometric shape over image, use someone from this tcpdf example: [php](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_012.phps), [pdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_012.pdf) ;

**Update:**

3. The most reliable way in this situation - make `png`  border  file with alpha channel, and use functions from [this example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_042.phps) [(pdf)](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_042.pdf) - [`TCPDF::Image()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352) `$ismask` & `$imgmask` attrs;
   Like in 2 case: draw image and after, draw `png` over main image:
   [image]

   PHP code:

   ```php
   $pdf->Image('/images/g1.jpg', 1, 1, '', '', '', '', '', false, 300);
   $pdf->Image('/images/border.png', 1, 1, '', '', '', '', '', false, 300);
   ```

   Result:

   [image]

   [Border `.png` file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKN4T.png);
   [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le2Ce.jpg);

Comment: circle I can use. Image() inside circle can I use or not ? if yes then image will get the shape of circle or not ?

Comment: I have my image.php file which creates resized image and tcpdf does not support it. That is why I use Image();

Comment: @CavidKərimov I can't resolve this problem with `Circle()` way;

Comment: @CavidKərimov I will try to provide as an example, for 3 case throughout the day;

Comment: @CavidKərimov OK. I finally did it =)

Comment: This is not an effective way, it doesn't work in cases where background is complex, and requires changes every time the background changes a bit.